# Most Recent Documents / Items with Sort and Filter functionality

Tags: web-part, filter, sorting

I want to have a Webpart that displays the Most Recent Documents for the entire site collection.

Main concern with this webpart is that there is a requirement for Filter and Sort functionality for metadata.

I was trying to find out of the box webparts but wasn't able to find anything similar to this requirement.

Has anyone implemented something of the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this OOTB.

If you dont feel like developing your own web part, check out this one from codeplex:
http://myrecentdocuments.codeplex.com/

If it does not fulfill your requirement, use it as a base a dev on it.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks JP! I was afraid of that. Ok, thanks! Will try to have discussions where to go to from here :)